# Is there a surface with negative total mean curvature in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces, curvature

Let $\Sigma$ be a closed and embedded surface of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Since it must be orientable, let $N$ be a unit normal for $\Sigma$ pointing towards the bounded component of $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \Sigma$. Is it possible that $\Sigma$ has negative total mean curvature, that is,

$$\int_\Sigma H \, \mathrm{d}A < 0?$$

I adopt the convention that the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ has mean curvature equal to $1$ when such a choice of normal has been made.

Comment: Just to give a little geometric insight: This is equivalent to requiring that the first variation of area if you deform the surface by pushing it in the direction of the unit *outer* normal be negative. I haven't worked on this, but perhaps if you cap off a minimal surface with a concave cap (controlling the integral along the bending along the seam) it might work.